# Child processes in kubernetes

Tags: linux, docker, debugging, logging, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy an instance of [hubcommander](https://github.com/Netflix/hubcommander) in our kubernetes cluster. Unlike other apps we are running there, this app is using a [shell script](https://github.com/yaron-idan/hubcommander/blob/develop/launch_in_docker.sh) as an entrypoint, which launches the python process only after performing some bootstrap steps.
This presents a problem because the child process running python is not printing logs to stdout, and so when I try to troubleshoot the process by using `kubectl logs <pod>` I get nothing but the logs written by the entrypoint script.

This behaviour is not reproduced locally, where running the container in the exact same manner shows logs from both the main and the child process.

Is there any way to tell the bash script to execute python in the same PID? or make it send logs to the same stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I've found out the lack of logs has nothing to do with the creation of a child process.
It was rather due to the fact python buffers output by default.
Executing the process using the `'u'` flag solved the issue for me.

Comment: This answer was a life saver!

For more context on the `u` flag, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559108/child-processes-in-kubernetes.